# Firing a click event on a button when the event is added to all buttons to reveal the clicked button text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I added the click event to all buttons but my intention is to have the event occur on a button inorder to extract the buttons text(btnText).

I have tried the `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` methods but its still not working as I expected.

```
<ul>
  <li><button>Dog</button></li>
  <li><button>Cat</button></li>
  <li><button>Moose</button></li>
</ul>
```

```
$('button').click(() => {
        $('button').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        let btnText = $(this).text(); *// expected result(Dog|Cat|Moose)*
        console.log(btnText); *// printed result (DogCatMoose)*
}); // end click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which makes `this` refer to the outer scope which `this` is [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), you need to use [`function declaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) instead to make `this` refers to the clicked `button`.

```js
$('button').click(function () {
        $('button').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        let btnText = $(this).text(); // expected result(Dog|Cat|Moose)*
        console.log(btnText); // printed result (DogCatMoose)*
}); // end click
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><button>Dog</button></li>
  <li><button>Cat</button></li>
  <li><button>Moose</button></li>
</ul>
```